# Unity error with object reference only occurring on iphone

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

This code should be called on login, perform the login and if successfull it should bring the user settings and convert them from json to classes using Newtonsoft Json .net.
In the editor and android no problems arise. However when running on IOS the login works alright but when getting the scenes it seems not to be parsing the data correctly.

**xcode error:**

d__12:MoveNext()
UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine:InvokeMoveNext(IEnumerator, IntPtr)

1
d__12:MoveNext()
UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine:InvokeMoveNext(IEnumerator, IntPtr)

NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at System.Linq.Expressions.Interpreter.LightLambda.MakeRunDelegateCtor (System.Type delegateType) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0
at

**the code in question**

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;


using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;


public class DatabaseConnection : MonoBehaviour
{
    public MainMenu menu;
    public string musername;
    public string mpassword;
    public string returnArray; 
    public int currentSession;
    public int lastSessUnlcoked=1;
    public UserProf userInfo;
    public List <SessionSettings> settingsList = new List<SessionSettings> ();
    public static DatabaseConnection Instance;
        void Awake (){
        if(Instance!=null){
            Destroy(this);
        }else{
            Instance=this;
        }
    }
    void Start (){
        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
    }
    public void Login(){
        musername=LoginManager.username;
        mpassword=LoginManager.pass;
        StartCoroutine(UploadLogin(musername,mpassword));
    }
    IEnumerator GetSessionData()
    {
        WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
        
        form.AddField("user_id",userInfo.id);
        using (UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post("http://localhost/spark/clases/UnityGetSettings.php", form))
        {
            yield return www.SendWebRequest();

            if (www.result != UnityWebRequest.Result.Success)
            {
                Debug.Log(www.error);
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log (www.downloadHandler.text);
                returnArray=www.downloadHandler.text;
                var sts =  JObject.Parse(returnArray);
                var AllSsessions = sts["Items"];
                foreach(var currentSession in AllSsessions){
                    var initials = currentSession["initialAssessment"];
                    List<Question> InitialAssessment = new List<Question> ();
                    List<Question> FinalAssessment = new List<Question> ();
                    List<LevelSettings> levelsList = new List<LevelSettings> ();
                    List<idStringClass> Summary = new List<idStringClass> ();
                    List<idStringClass> Debrief = new List<idStringClass> ();
                    foreach(var initial in initials){
                        string quest = initial["question"].ToObject<string>();
                        Debug.Log(initial["Id"]);
                        var qid = initial["Id"].Value<int>();
                        string type = initial["typeOfQuestion"].ToObject<string>();
                        List<Answer>answers=new List<Answer>();
                        var answrs = initial["answers"];
                        foreach(var answr in answrs){
                            var answer = answr.ToObject<Answer>();
                            answers.Add(answer);
                        }
                        var question = new Question(qid, quest, answers, type);
                        InitialAssessment.Add(question);
                    }
                    var finals = currentSession["finalAssessment"];
                    foreach(var final in finals){
                        int qid = final["Id"].ToObject<int>();
                        string quest = final["question"].ToObject<string>();
                        string type = final["typeOfQuestion"].ToObject<string>();
                        List<Answer>answers=new List<Answer>();
                        var answrs = final["answers"];
                        foreach(var answr in answrs){
                            int id = answr["Id"].ToObject<int>();
                            string text = answr["Text"].ToObject<string>();
                            string feedback = answr["Feedback"].ToObject<string>();
                            int imgId = answr["imgId"].ToObject<int>();
                            var answer = new Answer(id, text, feedback, imgId);
                            answers.Add(answer);
                        }
                        var question = new Question(qid,quest, answers, type);
                        FinalAssessment.Add(question);
                    }
                    var levels = currentSession["levels"];
                    foreach(var level in levels){
                        string type = level["gameName"].ToObject<string>();
                        if(type == "gonogo"){
                            var lvl = level.ToObject<GonogoSettings>();
                            levelsList.Add(lvl);
                        }else if (type == "treasure_hunt"){
                            var lvl = level.ToObject<THuntSettings>();
                            levelsList.Add(lvl);
                        }
                    }
                    var summaries = currentSession["assessment_summary"];
                    foreach(var summary in summaries){
                        var sum = summary.ToObject<idStringClass>();
                        Summary.Add(sum);
                    }
                    var debriefs = currentSession["assessment_debrief"];
                    foreach(var debrief in debriefs){
                        var deb = debrief.ToObject<idStringClass>();
                        Debrief.Add(deb);
                    }
                    settingsList.Add(new SessionSettings(1, 1, InitialAssessment, FinalAssessment, levelsList, Summary, Debrief));
                }
                var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(settingsList[0]);
                Debug.Log("json"+json);
                SceneManager.LoadScene("LevelSelection");
            }
        }
    }

    IEnumerator UploadLogin(string username, string password)
    {
        WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
        form.AddField("username",username);
        form.AddField("password",password);
        using (UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post("http://localhost/spark/clases/UnityLogin.php", form))
        {
            yield return www.SendWebRequest();

            if (www.result != UnityWebRequest.Result.Success)
            {
                Debug.Log(www.error);
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log (www.downloadHandler.text);
                returnArray=www.downloadHandler.text;
                userInfo=JsonUtility.FromJson<UserProf>(returnArray);
                StartCoroutine(GetSessionData());
            }
        }
    }

    
}
```

Comment: probably not related but why do you wait until `Start` to call `DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);`? I would directly do this in `Awake` along with assigning `Instance`

Comment: @derHugo you were onto something with the DontDestroy, in testing i realized that although it worked in the editor, i couldn't see the GameObject persisting in the hierarchy tab and it seems that that's the problem because it does parse and fetch the data alright on IOS but it dissappears once out of the original Scene. However I have tried putting the DontDestroy on awake but nothing changed

Answer (score 1):

```
UnityWebRequest.Post("http://localhost/spark/clases/UnityGetSettings.php", form))
```

`localhost` works on your development PC because apparently your server instance is running on that very same PC.

On your phone device it tries to contact `localhost` but the server isn't running on your phone but rather still on your dev PC.

=> You will need to rather use the according IP / host name of wherever your serer is actually running and reachable.

Additionally you might then need to ensure this address can actually be reached by your phone (DNS, network, routing, firewall, etc)